# how to return query value in a variable ( customerData )#Nodejs nodejs postgres

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, node-postgres

The code with the query:

```
var customerData =  pool.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
licensenumber = $1 AND phone = $2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ',
[Licensenumber,phone], (error, result) => {
if (error) {
throw error}
res.status(200).json(result.rows)
})
```

How can I return the result from the query?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear and also you posted a very limited portion of code, i guessed you wanted to do something like:

```js
try {
 const customerData = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE licensenumber = $1 AND phone = $2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ', [Licensenumber,phone]);
 res.status(200).json(customerData.rows);
} catch (e) { console.error(`An error occured: ${e}`); }
```

The documentation says promises are supported so first you `await` for the response and then send it to the client.

EDIT: some tips:

- always prefer `const` and `let`, `var` should not be used due to scope problems
- always prefer to use promises instead of callbacks to avoid the [`callback-hell`](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: How to i store my query return value in a variable In Nodejs ..

Comment: You just did with `const res = await pool.query()`